# How to convert Python list containing single quotes as well as double quotes values to all Double quotes values

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I want to convert python list containing single quotes as well as double quotes to all values with double quotes
I want to do this because i want to convert that list to tuples and than give that tuples output to postgresql query

I have tried JSON dumps method but didnt worked either because you cannot convert JSON list to tuples to give the tuple as the output to postgresql query

```
list = ['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]
```

Want output as:-

```
list = ["parrot", "dog", "leopard's", "cat", "zebra's"]
```

Comment: There is no difference between both lists

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between both for python:

```
>>> list = ['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]
>>> list2 = ["parrot", "dog", "leopard's", "cat", "zebra's"]
>>> list == list2
True
```

You can convert them to tuples, and they would still be the same:

```
>>> tuple(list) == tuple(list2)
True
```

The usage of `""` or `''` is just a representation of the string "constructor", and it only changes if you have the other kind of quotes inside the string.

Comment: I want to convert this list to tuples and give this tuples to postgresql query which requires all the values to be in single quotes or double quotes.

Comment: @Shubham, you are missing something, because there is no difference, you can call `tuple` on any of those list and they would still be  the same

Comment: Thank you for reply but, ```Postgres``` query doesn't accept tuples containing single quotes and double quotes it requires all the values to be in either single quotes or Double Quotes

Comment: @Shubham, post the error in the question so we can check, because you may be sending a simple string with bad formatting.

Comment: Is there any Method to change this list ```list = ['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]```  to this Double quotes List ```list = ["parrot", "dog", "leopard's", "cat", "zebra's"]]```

Comment: @Shubham, I answered to that, there is no difference in python between the both lists, it is just how it is shown to you.

Comment: i know that there is no difference between both of the list in python but I want to convert this list to double quotes so is there any method available to do that

Comment: @Shubham there is no difference... are you using Python and a library for postgres to connect and work with postgres? If so - you don't need to worry about any quoting at all - just include what you want to send (as a list or tuple - even mixed strings/datetimes/ints/floats) and the db api sorts it all out for you.

Comment: @JonClements But as all the values are not in same quotes which is single or double its throwing error showing that column doesn't exist ```ProgrammingError: column "Women's Sunglasses" does not exist```

Comment: @Shubham, that is not due to what you think. You better check your DB table columns.

Comment: @Shubham this isn't to do with Python per se... this is how you're interacting with postgres... What you should do is edit your question to include how/what you're trying to do from Python with postgres... the issue is there... the question you've currently asked isn't actually where the problem is or what you should be asking :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter single quotes or double quotes it is, but you will have some troubles if will use names that already has default values.

```
list_1 = ['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]
tuple_new = tuple(list_1)
```

This part of code can help you to make a tuple from list.

```
>>>list_1
['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]
>>>tuple(list_1)
('parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's")
```

You get a tuple of strings anyway.

And if you will try to make it by the way you want to python will return this:

```
>>list_1
['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]

>>'leopard\'s'
"leopard's"

>>'parrot'
'parrot'

>>"parrot"
'parrot'
```

**I found the way you can make it.**

```
>>list1 = ['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]
>>str1 = json.dumps(list1)
>>str1 = str1.replace("[", "")
>>str1 = str1.replace("]", "")
>>list2 = str1.split(", ")
>>list2
['"parrot"', '"dog"', '"leopard\'s"', '"cat"', '"zebra\'s"']
```

Comment: Is there any Method to change this list ```list = ['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]``` to this Double quotes List ```list = ["parrot", "dog", "leopard's", "cat", "zebra's"]```

Comment: @Shubham, I have edit my answer as you can see. Python automatically change quotes. I think you can try to write every element as string in postgresql's tuple. But your error have to have another problem. Maybe you can post the log of it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but problem is that i am getting this list output from another ```postgresql``` select query so i cannot hardcode the list value as they will change that's why i need to convert this list values to double quotes.

Comment: @Shubham, You can iterate list and convert its values: `for e in list1: e=str(e)` something like this

Comment: @Shubham, Can you try my last edition. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for reply but it didn't worked either because the output was list and when converting the JSON list to tuples it gives different output which cant be given as input to postgres query

Answer (score 0):

As per your suggestion

```
>>> list = ['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]
>>> import json
>>> print(json.dumps(list))
["parrot", "dog", "leopard's", "cat", "zebra's"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply i cannot convert this JSON list values to tuples

Comment: because `json.dumps` returns a string not a list of strings. It is different the type of something and its representation